# Google Contacts PHP Query Returning Blank Results

Tags: php, api, contacts

In my Google account, the domain name of my site is listed as having been granted access to Google Contacts.

So I would expect the URL below and its corresponding code to echo a list of all my Gmail contacts.  But it simply returns a blank page.  Any idea why it does not echo a list of all my Gmail contacts?

Thanks in advance,

John

URL:  `http://domain.com/gcontacts2.php`

Code:

```
<?php

$contacts = $_GET ['https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/arizona.williams%40gmail.com/full']; 


echo $contacts;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Permission error. A simple ip relation to your domain doesn't grant you access to the accounts contacts. Read the api about authenticating youself with arizona williams' account.

That is also NOT how you return the data of a page.... Look into using apache gets or curl. You're getting the "get" data from a browser request (similar to a post request or posted cookie).